# how i can login to my router in python without selenium

Tags: python

how i can login to my router in python without selenium

```
  <div class="panelThre" align="center">
        <div align="center" class="picDiv">
            <ul>
                <li id="unLi" class="unLi"><img src="../img/login/username.png"><input class="text" id="userName" type="text" maxlength="15" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off"/></li>
                <li class="blank"></li>
                <li id="pwLi" class="pwLi"><img src="../img/login/password.png"><input class="text" id="pcPassword" type="password" maxlength="15" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"/></li>
            </ul>           
            
            <label id="loginBtn" class="loginBtn" onclick="PCSubWin()"/><span id="loginBtnText">Login</span></label>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked into beautiful soup?

Comment: I used mechanicalsoup and mechanize but There is no form on my router page